# How do you run a RSpec::ExampleGroup which hasn't been written to file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I open up a rails console and require `rspec_rails`. I want to write a test like the following and be able to call it.

```
RSpec.describe("foo") do
  it "bar" do
    expect(false).to be false
  end
end
```

When I enter this into my console I see that a `RSpec::ExampleGroup::Foo` is created. However, I don't know how to call it.

I'm basically trying to reuse some helper methods I wrote for my tests. For example, I wrote a helper method called `create_user_and_login` which sends HTTP requests to a running server and creates a new user. I could reuse this method when migrating data our old database, but the method calls `expect` because up to now, it was only called from `RSpec::ExampleGroup` using the standard RSpec CLI runner.

Comment: As for the underlying problem: if you want to reuse methods across tests and non-tests, you have to decouple the helpers from any test code (like `expect`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how you can write and call that test in your console

```
# in your terminal
rails c test

# this worked for me to get rspec working in my console
require 'rspec/rails'

my_test = RSpec.describe("foo") do
  it "bar" do
    expect(false).to be false
  end
end

# now run it
my_test.run
# => true
```